# PostgreSQL, have a column as a sum function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need the column PrijsExBTW from Factuur to be the total value from all the Prijs from factuuritem where the factuurfactuurnummer from factuuritem is the same as the factuurnummer from factuur

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

See database model for the references:

[image: database model]

Answer (score 2):

This should be it.

```
update Factuur f
set PrijsExBTW = (select sum(Prijs) from factuuitem where factuurfactuurnummer = f.factuurnummer)
```